# How to check whether any file in the directory has a given string

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
Folder_name = "D:\newfolder\xxx"
echo "enter keyword"
read string
if grep $string $Folder_name;
then
  echo "yes"
else
  echi "no"
fi
```

Comment: `D:\newfolder\xxx` is a DOS/Windows pathname, not Unix.

Comment: Do you need to recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: There shouldn't be any space around `=`. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Folder_name=/newfolder/xxx
echo "enter keyword"
read string
if grep -q -F "$string" "$Folder_name"/*
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

1. There are no spaces around `=` in shell variable assignments.
2. `grep` requires filename arguments, not directories, unless you use the `-r` option to search the directory recursively.
3. The `-q` option tells `grep` not to print the matching lines.
4. The `-F` option tells it to treat `$string` as a verbatim string rather than a regular expression.
5. You should quote variables in case they contain whitespace or wildcard characters.

Comment: Its error in finding the directory. How to provide the exact path

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just put it in the `Folder_name` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Yes/No response, you can use this one line command:

```
grep -q $string $Folder_name/* && echo 'Yes'|| echo 'No'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say

```
found=false
for file in *; do
    if grep -q "$string" "$file"; then
        found=true
        break
    fi
done
if $found; then
    echo "at least one file contains $string"
else
    echo "no files contain $string"
fi
```

Comment: Does the astrix '*' int "`for file in *;`" means all commandline arguments?

Comment: No, it means "all filenames in current directory" (see [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)). If you want all commandline arguments: `for file in "$@"` -- the quotes are important.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a file that **contains** a particular string, or are you looking for a file name that contains a particular string?

#### File that contains a string:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "string" {} \;
```

#### File name that contains a particular string:

```
find . -type f | grep "string"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to search

```
  cd "$Folder_name" && count=$(grep -R -c "$string")
  if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
      echo "Yes"
  else
      echo "No"
  fi
```

This would recursively search for all files in the folder.